# Emulator for samsung galaxy tab 10.1

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-emulator

Is there an emulator for the samsung galaxy tab 10.1, I am using Eclipse builder.Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Emulator specific to Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 is not available. 
I guess a normal AVD with Target set to Android 3.1 should work as well.

Comment: wht density,size(resolution) & moniter dpi should be der while creating emulator for galaxy tab 10.1 wit android 3.1 ???

Comment: density - 160, resolution - 1280x800. Monitor Dpi depends on your monitor, mine shows 92.